# Download html with dynamic-css as pdf using python or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, css

I have a html-content with dynamic-css in python class which will be later passed to a js file. I need to download this html-content as pdf format.

I have gone through various html to pdf convertor tools(pdfkit,pdfcrowd,wkhtmltopdf) but none of them is able to render the dynamic css content.

I have even tried using windows.document.documentElement for obtaining html content with dynamic css rendered. 
But this did not work.

My question is: can we generate dynamic css seperately on python or download the complete pdf using js?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have used JSPDF to download pdf from html. It is easy to use. It should help you in your case: 
JS Fiddle Html to pdf: `http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/`

JSPDF Site `https://parall.ax/products/jspdf`